# Ryanair - Gate bag after November 1, 2018

Tags: luggage, hand-luggage, ryanair

Ryanair introduced its carry-on bag policy from November 2018. I assumed that I can take only 1 small bag. On their [website](https://corporate.ryanair.com/news/new-bag-policy-from-november-will-cut-check-bag-fees-reduce-boarding-delays/) they write:

> If non-priority customers want to bring a 2nd bigger (wheelie) bag they can buy a lower cost 10kg check bag for €/£8 at time of booking (currently a 20kg bag costs €/£25). This 10kg wheelie bag must be checked in at the airport bag drop desk.

And also:

> 6. What happens if my ‘small’ bag doesn’t fit in the sizer?
>
> If non-priority customers’ 1 free small bag doesn’t fit in the new sizer then their bag is more than 25% bigger than their small bag allowance. They will pay a gate bag fee of €25 and their bag will be tagged and placed in the hold. (See point 5)

But today I just received an email from Ryanair:

> Non-Priority: If you have not purchased Priority & 2 Cabin Bags, you are only permitted to bring 1 small personal bag on board (max 35cm x 20cm x 20cm) that must fit under the seat in front of you. **Your second bigger 10kg cabin bag** (max 55cm x 40cm x 20cm) will be tagged at the boarding gate and **put into the hold free of charge** and can be collected at the baggage carousel on arrival.

Note: I bought the tickets after 1 Sept 2018 (see [2.](https://corporate.ryanair.com/news/new-bag-policy-from-november-will-cut-check-bag-fees-reduce-boarding-delays/)).

There seems to be confounding information about it:

Supports the information in the email:
[Confused about Ryanair cabin bag policy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/120437/confused-about-ryanair-cabin-bag-policy)

Supports the information on the website:
https://thepointsguy.com/news/ryanair-introduces-new-confusing-baggage-fees/ and
https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/help-centre/faq-overview/Baggage#0-0 and
https://www.skyparksecure.com/blog/avoid-extra-ryanair-charges/ and https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/117394/89451

Comment: What is your question? Are you planning to fly with a certain number of bags and wondering how much it will cost you? Then please add the number, size and weight of your bags to the question. Otherwise, please edit your question so that there is an actual question that can be answered.

Comment: @Sabine I think the question is quite clear: Which one of these contradictory policies is in operation?

Comment: @MJeffryes while they might be very confusing, they are in no way contradictory. I will typ up an answer according to your suggested question, trying to clarify things.

Comment: Okay, after digging through Ryanairs website, it looks like the pieces of information are indeed contradicting. I thought the first snippet referred to bringing one small and two medium bags, when - after checking the website - it seems to cover the case of bringing one small and one medium bag. However, the second snippet should probably removed from the question, as this only refers to the "small" bag exceeding the allowed dimensions of a "small" bag and has nothing to do with the two other snippets..

Answer (score 2):

*Background.* RyanAir used to allow two bags per passenger as cabin luggage, free of charge: a small item (e.g. purse, laptop, small bag) and an additional bigger luggage (typically a small wheel suitcase or a backpack, less than 10kg and which can fit in the overhead locker). But they said that too many passengers were bringing oversized luggage and this was causing delays, so they started a much stricter (and incidentally more profitable) policy.

From now on, a passenger who doesn't pay any supplement can only bring one small bag:

> All passengers are entitled to bring 1 small personal bag on board
>   which must fit under the seat in front of you (40cm x 20cm x 25cm).
>   Examples include, handbag, laptop bag and small backpack.

In order to bring an additional piece of luggage, one must pay for one of these two options:

1. "priority and 2 cabin bags": the passenger can bring an additional bag in the cabin (10kg, 55  x 40 x 20cm). This allows you to bring as much luggage as before the change took place, but now you pay for it.

> Passengers who have purchased "Priority & 2 Cabin Bags" or
>   Plus/Flexi/Family ticket or connecting flight ticket can bring 1
>   additional 10kg bag on board which must fit into the baggage sizer
>   (not exceeding 10kg and dimensions 55cm x 40cm x 20cm).

2. "10kg check-in bag": as the name suggests, this means that the luggage has to be checked in (**not** brought in the cabin). Advantage: cabin restrictions about size or forbidden items don't apply. This new option is cheaper than the standard 20kg check-in bag.

> Non-priority customers who wish to bring a second larger wheelie bag
>   (10kg weight) must purchase the 10kg Check-in Bag.   The 10kg wheelie
>   bag must be checked-in at the airport bag drop desk prior to entering
>   security.

https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/help-centre/faq-overview/Baggage/cabin-bag-policy